# Record not updating on successful insert

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a row as shown in below image

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g84Q8.png)

**I am fetching id and name from db and other select options are to be updated in particular row.**

My id and name fetching as shown below

```
$sql = "SELECT id, name,day,week,month,pickup,drop_location FROM crm LIMIT 10";
        $resultset = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("database error:". mysqli_error($conn));
        while( $emp = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultset) ) {        
        ?>  
            <tr style="text-align: center;">  
                <td><?php echo $emp["id"]; ?></td>
```

I am updating row but it is not working.

**form.php**

```
<form action="drop.php" name = "myForm" method="post">
                <td id="s1">    
                    <select style="width: 150px;" class="blue" id="pick" data-style="btn-info" name="pickup">
                        <option value="ward" id="ward1">Floor 1</option>
                        <option value="ward1" id="ward2">Floor 2</option>
                        <option value="ward2" id="ward3">Floor 3</option>
                    </select>

                </td>
                <td id="s2">
                    <select style="width: 150px;" class="blue" id="drop" data-style="btn-success" name="drop_location">
                        <option value="ward"  id="ward1">Floor 1</option>
                        <option value="ward1" id="ward2">Floor 2</option>
                        <option value="ward2" id="ward3">Floor 3</option>
                    </select>

                </td>
                <td id="s3">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit">submit</button>
                    <select style="width: 150px;" class="blue" id="stat" data-style="btn-warning" name="stat">

                        <option value="allocate">Allocated</option>
                        <option value="cancel">Cancelled</option>   
                    </select>

                </td>  

                <td id="s4">
                    <select style="width: 150px;" class="blue" id="status" data-style="btn-primary" name="status">
                        <option value="pending">pending</option>
                        <option value="Allocated">Allocated</option>
                        <option value="Engaged">Engaged</option>
                    </select>

                </td>  

            </form>
            </tr>
```

**drop.php**

```
 <?php
    /* Attempt MySQL server connection. Assuming you are running MySQL
    server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "redeem");

    // Check connection
    if($mysqli === false){
        die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . $mysqli->connect_error);
    }


    // Escape user inputs for security
    $pickup = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['pickup']);
    $drop_location = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['drop_location']);
    $stat = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['stat']);
    $status = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['status']);

    // attempt insert query execution
    $sql = "UPDATE crm SET pickup='$pickup',drop_location='$drop_location',stat='$stat', status='$status' WHERE id = 'id' ";

    if($mysqli->query($sql) === true){
        echo "Records inserted successfully.";
    } else{
        echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . $mysqli->error;
    }

    // Close connection
    $mysqli->close();
    ?>
```

I have created id for the select like this

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
$("#pick, #drop, #stat, #status").on('change', function () {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

I am not able to figure where the mistake is. Please, kindly help me out.

Thank you in Advance!!!

Comment: `WHERE id = 'id' ` isn't probably the right id to use.

Comment: What error are you getting right now?

Comment: that's because you did not specify the `ID` to be updated

Comment: how can i update the id

Comment: You could add a hidden field to your form with the ID and then pick it up in the `$_POST` values.

Comment: @NigelRen can you please tell me how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are already fetching the records from database so what you need inside your form have a hidden field that will have a value of each record's id.

add this in your form :

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$emp['id']?>">
```

Then you can be able to update the record using that id, I also suggest that you use prepared statement to prevent sql injections.

```
<?php
/* Attempt MySQL server connection. Assuming you are running MySQL
server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "redeem");

// Check connection
if ($mysqli === false) {
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . $mysqli->connect_error);
}



$pickup        = isset($_POST['pickup']) ? $_POST['pickup'] : null;
$drop_location = isset($_POST['drop_location']) ? $_POST['drop_location'] : null;
$stat          = isset($_POST['stat']) ? $_POST['stat'] : null;
$status        = isset($_POST['status']) ? $_POST['status'] : null;
$id            = isset($_POST['id']) ? intval($_POST['id']) : null;


// attempt insert query execution
$sql = "UPDATE crm SET pickup = ? ,drop_location= ? ,stat= ? , status= ?  WHERE id = ? ";

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql); //prepare statement
$stmt->bind_param("ssssi", $pickup, $drop_location, $stat, $status, $id);


if ($mysqli->execute()) { //execute the query
    echo "Records inserted successfully.";
} else {
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . $mysqli->error;
}

// Close connection
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: Thanks bro that really helped me a lot. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You are not taking which Id need to be updated. And In query you are using `id = 'id'` need to replace id with $id variable to update the value.

```
// Escape user inputs for security
    $pickup = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['pickup']);
    $drop_location = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['drop_location']);
    $stat = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['stat']);
    $status = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['status']);
    $id= $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['id']);   // Get id from post need to be updated

    // attempt insert query execution
    $sql = "UPDATE crm SET 
            pickup='$pickup',drop_location='$drop_location',stat='$stat', status='$status' 
            WHERE id = $id ";   // use $id variable

    if($mysqli->query($sql) === true){
        echo "Records inserted successfully.";
    } else{
        echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . $mysqli->error;
    }
```

Comment: how can i take that

Comment: when you are creating the above form you need to put primary key of that record in hidden field and while posting you can fetch it and update the record.

Comment: @Naincy can you please help me with that query.

Comment: `// Escape user inputs for security` how does `real_escape_string()` strengthen security? @Naincy